# Не работают ссылки, вставленные с помощью метода .html()

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Полученные с сервера ссылки не реагируют на функцию.

---

```
$("a").live('click', function () {
    $('.result').fadeOut('fast');
    history.pushState(null, null, this.href);
    var returnLocation = history.location || document.location;

    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php?link=" + returnLocation,
        cache: false,
        success: function (phpserverdata) {
            $('.result').fadeIn('fast', function () {
                $('.result').html(phpserverdata); //Полученный html код вставлен, но полученные ссылки не реагируют на данную функцию. 
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Версия библиотеки 1.8.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

[Документация](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Попробуйте

```
$("body").on('click', 'a', function() { ... })
```

вместо

```
$("a").live('click' ,function() { ... })
```

Comment: Только хорошо бы сузить круг необходимых ссылок и делегировать от ближайшего родительского статичного блока. В данном случае, как я понимаю, это блок с классом **result**, т.е.

    $('.result').on('click', 'a', function() { /*...*/ });